# OpenGL Rotation of multiple Objects is overwritten in draw-loop

Tags: c++, matrix, opengl, rotation, glm-math

I want to create a rubiks cube where each side contains multiple cubes. So far I'm able to create the overall Cube. I now want to rotate one side of the cube to the left, to do this i create a new matrix and then bind the uniform to that matrix. This works fine, but if i do a second operation, like rotating a different side, I again create a new matrix with the rotation and bind the uniform to that matrix. After i draw my objects after the second rotation, my objects are reset to the initial matrix (rotations are reverted).

Code for the left rotation:

```
glm::mat4 spinLeft(glm::mat4 anim, GLuint shaderProgram, int i) {
     if(i < 9) {
        // createAnim(shaderProgram, anim);
        if(nrRotations <= 900) {
            anim = spinObj(anim, 1.0);
            // cout << nrRotations << endl; 
            nrRotations += 1;
            glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformAnim, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(anim));

        }
    }
    return anim;
} 

glm::mat4 spinObj(glm::mat4 anim, float orientation) {
    float angle = 0.1f * orientation;

    anim = glm::rotate(anim, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f));
    
    return anim;
}
```

Code for the right rotation:

```
glm::mat4 spinRight(glm::mat4 anim, GLuint shaderProgram, int i) {
        if(i == RIGHT || i == TOP_RIGHT || i == BOTTOM_RIGHT  
            || i == RIGHT+9 || i == TOP_RIGHT+9 || i == BOTTOM_RIGHT+9  
            || i == RIGHT+18 || i == TOP_RIGHT+18 || i == BOTTOM_RIGHT+18)
        {
            // createAnim(shaderProgram, anim);
            if(nrRotations <= 900) {
                anim = spinObj2(anim, 1.0);
                // cout << nrRotations << endl; 
                nrRotations +=1; 
            glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformAnim, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(anim));

            }
        } 

    return anim;
}

glm::mat4 spinObj2(glm::mat4 anim, float orientation) {
    float angle = 0.1f * orientation;

    anim = glm::translate(anim, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.1f) );
    anim = glm::rotate(anim, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    anim = glm::translate(anim, -(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.1f)) );


    return anim;
}
```

Code responsible for drawing, the vtxArray is the array containing my cubes, which form the overall cube. With the createAnim function i bind a new matrix (which is simply the identity matrix). If i dont call the createAnim the cube is not reset to the initial cube, but i get the problem that all rows are rotating, and not just the 1 row i define.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i+=1) {
            createAnim(shaderProgram, anim);

            if(move == 1) {
                if(i < 9) {
                    anim2 = spinLeft(anim2, shaderProgram, i);
                    if(nrRotations == 900) {
                        move ++;
                        nrRotations = 0;
                        // anim = anim2;
                    }
                }
            } else if (move == 2) {
                anim3 = spinRight(anim3,shaderProgram, i);
                if (nrRotations == 900) {
                    move++;
                    nrRotations = 0;
                }
            }
          
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*36*4, &vtxArray[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW);  
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        }
```

I use 1 VBO and 1 VAO for this. I hope you understand the problem I'm having, let me know if more code or explanation is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to take advantage of matrix multiplication. There are many good resources online about how matrix multiplication can be used to "chain" rotations sequentially and is part of the intuition behind how the MVP matrix is chained together from seperate model, view and projection matrices without losing any of the information in the process.

In brief:

- iterate through all blocks in the Rubik's cube and filter the blocks that form the face you want to rotate (check if its position is a certain value)
- apply a rotation to its model matrix with matrix multiplication
- update uniform for block and draw

If you get stuck, here is an example based around the code from LearnOpenGL, which demonstrates chaining matrix multiplication:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

#include <learnopengl/camera.h>

#include <iostream>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>


using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using glm::mat4;
using glm::vec2;
using glm::vec3;
using glm::vec4;
using glm::perspective;
using glm::radians;
using glm::normalize;

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// grid dimensions
const unsigned int GRID_WIDTH = 600;
const unsigned int GRID_HEIGHT = 600;

float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

mat4 view;
mat4 projection;
float fov = 90.0f;

Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));

class Block {
public:
    unsigned int shaderProgram;
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;

    mat4 model;

    Block(vec3 pos=vec3(0,0,0)) {

        model = translate(mat4(1.0), pos);
        // scale it down a little bit to see the different blocks
        model = scale(model, vec3(0.99, 0.99, 0.99));

        float vertices[] = {
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 1,// 1
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 1,// 0
             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 1,// 2
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 1,// 0
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 1,// 3
             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 1,// 2

            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0, 1, 0,// 0
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0, 1, 0,// 1
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0, 1, 0,// 2
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0, 1, 0,// 2
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0, 1, 0,// 3
            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0, 1, 0,// 0

            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1, 0, 0,
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1, 0, 0,
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 0, 0,
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 0, 0,
            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1, 0, 0,
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1, 0, 0,

             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, // 1
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, // 0
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, // 2
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, // 0
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, // 3
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, // 2

            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 1,//0
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 1,//1
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1, 1, 1,//2
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1, 1, 1,//2
            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1, 1, 1,//3
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 1,//0

             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 0, //1
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 0, //0
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1, 1, 0, //2
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 0, //0
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1, 1, 0, //3
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1, 1, 0, //2

        };


        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // position attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // color attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
            "layout (location = 1) in vec3 aCol;\n"
            "uniform mat4 model;\n"
            "uniform mat4 view;\n"
            "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
            "out vec4 outColor;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
            "   outColor = vec4(aCol,1.0f);\n"
            "}\0";
        const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
            "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
            "in vec4 outColor;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   FragColor = outColor;\n"
            "}\n\0";

        // vertex shader
        int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        // fragment shader
        int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        // link shaders
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        // check for linking errors
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    }

    void setMatrix(std::string name, glm::mat4 mat) {
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }

    void draw() {
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    }


    vec3 getPosition() {
        return vec3(model[3]);
    }
};

class Cube {
public:
    vector<Block> blocks;
    Cube() {
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                for (int z = -1; z <= 1; z++) {
                    blocks.push_back(Block(vec3(x,y,z)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(mat4 view, mat4 projection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
            blocks[i].setMatrix("model", blocks[i].model);
            blocks[i].setMatrix("view", view);
            blocks[i].setMatrix("projection", projection);
            blocks[i].draw();           
        }

    }

    void rotate(std::string value, bool ccw) {
        int index;
        vec3 axis;
        if (value == "x") {
            index = 0;
            axis = vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        if (value == "y") {
            index = 1;
            axis = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
            if (fabs(blocks[i].getPosition()[index] - 1.0f) < 0.1f ) {
                // create rotation matrix
                mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(mat4(1.0f), radians(ccw ? -90.0f : 90.0f), axis);
                // multiply with current matrix
                blocks[i].model = rotationMatrix * blocks[i].model;
            }
        }
    }

};

Cube *rubiksCube;

int main()
{

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Rubik's Cube", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_button_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    projection = perspective(radians(fov), (float)SCR_WIDTH/(float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    rubiksCube = new Cube();

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;


        processInput(window);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        rubiksCube->draw(camera.GetViewMatrix(), projection);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    delete rubiksCube;

    return 0;
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);     

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}


// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}


void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_1 && action == 1) {
        rubiksCube->rotate("x", true);
    }
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_3 && action == 1) {
        rubiksCube->rotate("y", true);
    }

    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_2 && action == 1) {
        rubiksCube->rotate("x", false);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: rotating sides demo]